# AngularJS - Create both datasets and model bindings dynamically from database

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, binding, model

So.
This is my first Angular adventure, but I've been coding web from db to php to html/js since -97.

I'm using AngularJS v1.6.5, http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ and https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider in an app I'm building.
(Can't post all code or link to it due to customer)

In essence, I have a rest API fronting a database holding a number of areas which will each get a slider. Each slider will be bound to it's own dataset, and moving the sliders will affect elements in a number of charts through use of one more dataset holding a factor unique to each sliders area.

If I hardcode all the sliders and bind them to the right datasets it all works just as it should. each slider binds to it's own model, moving the sliders changes the data in the charts, great.

But since the database can get more areas, or fewer, I naturally want to create all the datasets for the models and the sliders from the db-data in the controller, and bind each slider to the right dataset through ng-repeat. To add to it, the same dataset will on change be passed from the slider to a service which does calculations before updating the charts.

My routing assigns the "ChartController as chart", and in the controller I do "var chartdata = this;" so I'm not using the actual $scope for the models.

In the controller I have one dataset holding the areas from the API which will get a slider, this holds a name and an id, then I will generate datasets for each slider holding the values for the sliders from another API call.

So I will in the controller generate multiple datasets from the data in the db, The idea was to name them like these where the Id of the slider area is the number at the end of the model-name:

```
//default slider settings from database
chartdata.slider_id_1 = 4;
chartdata.slider_id_2 = 3;
chartdata.slider_id_3 = 2;
chartdata.slider_id_4 = 6;
chartdata.slider_id_5 = 4;
chartdata.slider_id_6 = 7;
chartdata.slider_id_7 = 3;
chartdata.slider_id_8 = 9;
chartdata.slider_id_9 = 5;
chartdata.slider_id_10 = 8;
chartdata.slider_id_11 = 12;
chartdata.slider_id_12 = 1;
chartdata.slider_id_13 = 2;

// weighting for impact
chartdata.factor_id_1 = 0.24;
chartdata.factor_id_2 = 0.46;
chartdata.factor_id_3 = 0.97;
chartdata.factor_id_4 = 0.62;
chartdata.factor_id_5 = 0.125;
chartdata.factor_id_6 = 0.166;
chartdata.factor_id_7 = 0.33;
chartdata.factor_id_8 = 0.698;
chartdata.factor_id_9 = 0.489;
chartdata.factor_id_10 = 0.44;
chartdata.factor_id_11 = 0.12;
chartdata.factor_id_12 = 0.1;
chartdata.factor_id_13 = 0.22;
```

Then I have this in my template which iterates over the slider area dataset, this is where I would like to dynamically create the model names. ie. the chart.slider_id_XX and chart.factor_id_XX to map against the generated datasets.

```
<div ng-repeat="slider in chart.sliders">
<div flex="20" layout layout-align="center center" >
<span class="md-body-1">{{slider.Name}}</span>
</div>
<md-slider flex md-discrete ng-model="chart.slider_id_11" step="1" min="0" max="100" aria-label="{{slider.Name}}" id="{{slider.Id}}" ng-click="updateImpact(chart.slider_id_11,chart.factor_id_11);">
</md-slider>
</div>
```

So I can use the name and id of the sliderdata in some places, but not in the model binding where I, on the serverside would have concatenated together a string with the id from the slider object, but that does not work here, probably due to the order that javascript and ng-directives are processed.

I have looked at similar questions for a full day, but they tend to only solve one side of it, or seemingly, uses a collection of models and referring through array indexes, but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

I could resort to hardcoding it, just to get past the issue, but it would feel so stupid.

I have full control over all the code, everything from the SQL queries, to the data structure to the js code, and I'm not locked into the samples outlined above, so I'm quite flexible in implementing a smart, good practice solution, if there is one to be found.

Thankful for all and any help here!
/Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dynamic model binding like this.

Create a generic object to hold values for all sliders.

```
   $scope.SliderDTO = {};
```

Now bind ng-model in your sliders like this:

```
 <md-slider flex md-discrete ng-model="SliderDTO[slider.Name]" step="1" 
 min="0" max="100" aria-label="{{slider.Name}}" id="{{slider.Id}}" ng-
  click="updateImpact(chart.slider_id_11,chart.factor_id_11);">
 </md-slider>
```

Finally the selected values will be available like this:

For slider name slider_id_1 value will be in $scope.SliderDTO.slider_id_1

Comment: Thank you.
I have tried similar things to this before without getting it to work, but I'll give it another try :)

Comment: Thank you so very very much! 
I got everything to work perfectly this time, from dynamic generation of the sliders bound to each owns model, which I now also can generate dynamically, to passing correct parameters to the on-click function :)

Can't upvote due to my reputation too low, but flagged it as a working answer. Thank you again :)